# accord sth with sth?

Tags: phrases

> North Korea's state-run Korean Central News Agency also confirmed the
>   visit, saying Kim was "**accorded** cordial hospitality **with** utmost
>   sincerity to him in token of warm comradely friendship and friendly
>   feelings during his China visit."

I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? You've got to be more specific. If it's the verb *to accord* that you don't understand, then why didn't you look it up in a dictionary? Don't you know that questions that can be answered by consulting a dictionary usually get rather promptly closed here?

Answer (score 1):

Kim was accorded cordial hospitality. The hospitality was extremely sincere. That is, it was accorded to Kim with the utmost sincerity.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "accorded" means "given" or "granted". It's a slightly uncommon usage, more formal (maybe even florid) than common speech.